# Django Create and output txt file from view

Tags: python, django

I have a scenario where a user uploads some data, Django does some processing in pandas and returns a potentially large txt file. I've got this working but I'm unsure about the scalability of the approach and want to know if there's a better way.

Adapted the Outputting to CSV section of the Django doc I have the following:

```py
class MyClass(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
  template_name = 'myapp/mytemplate.html'
  form_class = MyForm
  success_url = '/'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
      form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  
      #print("filename",files[0].name)
      if form.is_valid()  : 
        filename = "my-file.txt"
        content = 'any string generated by django'
        response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)
        return response


      else:
        print("i am invalid")
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

In practice I will need to output a text file of perhaps 1000 lines, built by looping over numerous dataframes, should I just build an extremely long text string (content), or is there a better way? In pure python I am more used to creating txt file output using:

```py
f = open( 'some_file.txt', 'w+')
f.write("text")
f.write("text")
f.close()
```

Which seems more intuitive.

As requested by comments, updated to show exactly the code I was trying in Django which was returning an empty text file:

```py
class MyClass(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
  template_name = 'myapp/mytemplate.html'
  form_class = MyForm
  success_url = '/'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
      form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  
      if form.is_valid()  : 
        f = open( 'some_file.txt', 'w+')
        f.write("text")
        return FileResponse(f, as_attachment=True, filename='some_file.txt')
```

Comment: First you should fill your file with data and then send back this file as a response ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you provide an example of how I would do this. I tried this approach before but the txt file was empty:````python  f = open( 'some_file.txt', 'w+')
          f.write(text)
          #f.close()
          return FileResponse(f, as_attachment=True, filename='some_file.txt') ````

Comment: Your solution does not work ?

Comment: The code I posted in the comment creates an output file, but it's empty.

Comment: Also the latter approach seems to be writing the files out within my app, which I don't want. I want the file to be downloaded only.

Comment: Why it's empty ? you are doing something in a wrong way.
`with open('mytext.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write('a')
        f.write('b')`
This should work.

Comment: If you do not want to make `f.write()`, iterate over data create one big string and `f.write()` only once. `data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] _str = ''.join(data) f.write(_str)`

Comment: This works for me in pure python, but within Django the written file is empty.

Comment: Because i do not see code in your Django's view where you create file.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/plain')  
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filename.txt"'

response.write('Hello')

return response
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/outputting-csv/

It's same as CSV, just change extension to .txt

Example:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/plain')  
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filename.txt"'

writer = csv.writer(response)

writer.writerow(['Hello'])
```